# scala.sys.process.Process("ls").run().exitValue() with no output

Tags: scala, command-line, terminal

When I run Process(command), the output of the command is printed out to terminal, but I **only want the exitValue()**.

Is there a way to **suppress** the output displayed on terminal? I just find sometime the command processed could print a huge output result on terminal. Thanks a lot.

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> Process("ls").run().exitValue()
README.md
Vagrantfile
bin
box
config
package.sh
vendor
res6: Int = 0
```

Comment: I think I still like my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411728/scala-process-capture-standard-out-and-exit-code but Process is too complex to remember right. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927138/scala-get-list-of-directories-from-process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `run()` overload that takes a `ProcessLogger`. Use a `ProcessLogger` that ignores strings passed to `out` and `err`:

```
Process("ls").run(ProcessLogger(_ => ())).exitValue()
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to figure out whether your answer is better than the answers linked from my other comment. I guess that's why I don't use Process? It's very complex compared to sh. But I'll +1 b/c I'm too lazy not to.

Comment: maybe this one is more concise, less code :P, thank you all the same

Answer (score 2):

**Simple one line answer**

```
import scala.sys.process._

"ls" ! ProcessLogger(_ => ())
```

or

```
import scala.sys.process._

"ls" ! ProcessLogger(a => (), b  => ())
```

Gives only the exit value

**output**

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
scala> "ls" ! ProcessLogger(a => (), b  => ())
res11: Int = 0
```

Comment: I like this. I didn't know about those factory methods on the ProcessLogger object. There's another overload that takes a single function, so you could simply use `"ls" ! ProcessLogger(_ => ())`. I've updated my answer. Note that those `Unit`s don't do what you might think they do (pass `-Ywarn-value-discard` to scalac and see what happens).